# Powershell function dispose or abort handler

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a pipe function that allocates some resources in `begin` block that need to be disposed at the end. I've tried doing it in the `end` block but it's not called when function execution is aborted for example by `ctrl`+`c`.

How would I modify following code to ensure that `$sw` is always disposed:

```
function Out-UnixFile([string] $Path, [switch] $Append) {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Sends output to a file encoded with UTF-8 without BOM with Unix line endings.
    #>
    begin {
        $encoding = new-object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false)
        $sw = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($Path, $Append, $encoding)
        $sw.NewLine = "`n"
    }
    process { $sw.WriteLine($_) }
    # FIXME not called on Ctrl+C
    end { $sw.Close() }
}
```

**EDIT**: simplified function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to write it in C# where one can implement IDisposable - confirmed to be called by powershell in case of `ctrl`-`c`.

I'll leave the question open in case someone comes up with some way of doing it in powershell.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Internal;
using System.Text;

namespace MarcWi.PowerShell
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsData.Out, "UnixFile")]
    public class OutUnixFileCommand : PSCmdlet, IDisposable
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 0)]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public PSObject InputObject { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public SwitchParameter Append { get; set; }

        public OutUnixFileCommand()
        {
            InputObject = AutomationNull.Value;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (sw != null)
            {
                sw.Close();
                sw = null;
            }
        }

        private StreamWriter sw;

        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            base.BeginProcessing();
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            sw = new StreamWriter(FileName, Append, encoding);
            sw.NewLine = "\n";
        }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            sw.WriteLine(InputObject);
        }

        protected override void EndProcessing()
        {
            base.EndProcessing();
            Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no good solution for this. Deterministic cleanup seems to be a glaring omission in PowerShell. It could be as simple as introducing a new `cleanup` block that is always called regardless of how the pipeline ends, but alas, even version 5 seems to offer nothing new here (it introduces classes, but without cleanup mechanics).

That said, there are some not-so-good solutions. Simplest, if you enumerate over the `$input` variable rather than use `begin`/`process`/`end` you can use `try`/`finally`:

```
function Out-UnixFile([string] $Path, [switch] $Append) {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Sends output to a file encoded with UTF-8 without BOM with Unix line endings.
    #>
    $encoding = new-object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false)
    $sw = $null
    try {
        $sw = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($Path, $Append, $encoding)
        $sw.NewLine = "`n"
        foreach ($line in $input) {
            $sw.WriteLine($line)
        }
    } finally {
        if ($sw) { $sw.Close() }
    }
}
```

This has the big drawback that your function will hold up the entire pipeline until everything is available (basically the whole function is treated as a big `end` block), which is obviously a deal breaker if your function is intended to process lots of input.

The second approach is to stick with `begin`/`process`/`end` and manually process Control-C as input, since this is really the problematic bit. But by no means the *only* problematic bit, because you also want to handle exceptions in this case -- `end` is basically useless for purposes of cleanup, since it is only invoked if the entire pipeline is successfully processed. This requires an unholy mix of `trap`, `try`/`finally` and flags:

```
function Out-UnixFile([string] $Path, [switch] $Append) {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Sends output to a file encoded with UTF-8 without BOM with Unix line endings.
  #>
  begin {
    $old_treatcontrolcasinput = [console]::TreatControlCAsInput
    [console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true
    $encoding = new-object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false)
    $sw = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($Path, $Append, $encoding)
    $sw.NewLine = "`n"
    $end = {
      [console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $old_treatcontrolcasinput
      $sw.Close()
    }
  }
  process {
    trap {
      &$end
      break
    }
    try {
      if ($break) { break }
      $sw.WriteLine($_)
    } finally {
      if ([console]::KeyAvailable) {
        $key = [console]::ReadKey($true)
        if (
          $key.Modifiers -band [consolemodifiers]"control" -and 
          $key.key -eq "c"
        ) { 
          $break = $true
        }
      }
    }
  }
  end {
    &$end
  }
}
```

Verbose as it is, this is the shortest "correct" solution I can come up with. It does go through contortions to ensure the Control-C status is restored properly and we never attempt to catch an exception (because PowerShell is bad at rethrowing them); the solution could be slightly simpler if we didn't care about such niceties. I'm not even going to try to make a statement about performance. :-)

If someone has ideas on how to improve this, I'm all ears. Obviously checking for Control-C could be factored out to a function, but beyond that it seems hard to make it simpler (or at least more readable) because we're forced to use the `begin`/`process`/`end` mold.

Comment: There is also the option of writing it in C# where I can implement IDisposable and I think it's the best solution given current powershell limitations :(

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki: True, if you write your cmdlet in C# you can do anything. I didn't suggest that because it's cheating. :-) Actually, more realistically, whenever I'm faced with something that would require writing C# code, I typically write a LINQPad script instead. I then use PowerShell only for its powerful wildcard features, to get the initial file list my LINQPad script will operate on.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an implementation of "using" for PowerShell (from [Solutionizing .Net](http://solutionizing.net/2008/09/21/multi-purpose-powershell-using-function/)). `using` is a reserved word in PowerShell, hence the alias `PSUsing`:

```
function Using-Object {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Object]
        $inputObject = $(throw "The parameter -inputObject is required."),

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ScriptBlock]
        $scriptBlock
    )

    if ($inputObject -is [string]) {
        if (Test-Path $inputObject) {
            [system.reflection.assembly]::LoadFrom($inputObject)
        } elseif($null -ne (
              new-object System.Reflection.AssemblyName($inputObject)
              ).GetPublicKeyToken()) {
            [system.reflection.assembly]::Load($inputObject)
        } else {
            [system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($inputObject)
        }
    } elseif ($inputObject -is [System.IDisposable] -and $scriptBlock -ne $null) {
        Try {
            &$scriptBlock
        } Finally {
            if ($inputObject -ne $null) {
                $inputObject.Dispose()
            }
            Get-Variable -scope script |
                Where-Object {
                    [object]::ReferenceEquals($_.Value.PSBase, $inputObject.PSBase)
                } |
                Foreach-Object {
                    Remove-Variable $_.Name -scope script
                }
        }
    } else {
        $inputObject
    }
}

New-Alias -Name PSUsing -Value Using-Object
```

With example usage:

```
psusing ($stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $PSHOME\types.ps1xml) {             
    foreach ($_ in 1..5) { $stream.ReadLine() }             
}
```

Obviously this is really just some packaging around Jeroen's first answer but may be useful for others who find their way here.

Comment: This implementation doesn't work.  Unlike C#, PowerShell variable assignments evaluate to null.  So `$stream` is never passed to `Using-Object` and `.Dispose()` is never invoked.