# Stopping PowerShell pipeline, ensure end is called

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-4.0

What I'm trying to do is get a function to stop the pipeline feed when a time limit has been reached. I've created a test function as follows :

```powershell
function Test-PipelineStuff
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLIne=$true)][int]$Foo,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLIne=$true)][int]$MaxMins
    )

    begin { 
        "THE START" 
        $StartTime = Get-Date
        $StopTime = (get-date).AddMinutes($MaxMins)
        "Stop time is: $StopTime"
    } 

    process 
    {  
        $currTime = Get-Date
        if( $currTime -lt $StopTime ){
            "Processing $Foo"            
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }

    end { "THE END" }
}
```

This will certainly stop the pipeline, but it never calls my "end{}" block, which, in this case is vital. Does anyone know why my "end{}" block isn't being called when I stop the pipeline using "continue"? Behaviour seems to be the same if I throw a PipelineStoppedException.

Comment: Presumably `continue` is jumping out of its containing loop only there isn't one so it jumps clear of your entire function. That's not exactly helpful though. I'm not sure if there's a proper way to do what you are trying to do here.

Comment: As I understand it, cmdlets such as Select-Object -First 1 will raise the StopUpstreamCommandsException to stop the pipeline, which is an internal exception and not visible for my own use. :(

Comment: Maybe put your `end{}` processing into a different scriptblock that you can call from the `else{}` clause inside `process{}` ?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8749206/258523) seems relevant. Specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16968855/258523).

Comment: The [Pipeline.Stop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.stop%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method seems like it might also be useful but my limited powershell knowledge meant I couldn't figure out how to make that work in a quick test.

Comment: Just playing around with this--can you just put an invalid command there that will throw an error?  I put `stop-process "" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` where you have `continue`, and it ran the end block.

Comment: @TonyHinkle Did that actually stop the pipeline though?

Comment: Found somewhat similar issue, might be worth looking through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522507/powershell-function-dispose-or-abort-handler

Answer (score 2):

According to [about_Functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx):

> After the function receives all the objects in the pipeline, the End
>   statement list runs one time. If no Begin, Process, or End keywords
>   are used, all the statements are treated like an End statement list.

Thus you just need to omit the `else` block. Then all objects in the pipeline are processed, but due to the `if` clause the actual processing is only being done until the time limit is hit.

Comment: If I have to wait for it to process all of the objects in the pipeline, it pretty much negates the benefit of trying to tell it to stop at a certain time. I'm trying to get this script to stop if it hits the time limit, and avoid processing all of the items outside of that limit. Of course I can get the end block to execute if I process everything, but that's not my goal.

Comment: The question was, why the end block never gets called. The answer is, that it only gets called if all items in the pipeline are processed.

Comment: No, the question was how do I stop the pipeline and ensure the end gets called.

Answer (score 2):

Using `break` / `continue` or throwing an exception will invariably exit your function prematurely (and also break out of / continue any enclosing loop).

You can, however, embed a cleanup function in the `begin` block that implements what you originally put into your `end` block and call that function from *both* your `process` block - just before `continue` - *and* the `end` block:

```
function Test-PipelineStuff
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine=$true)][int]$Foo,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine=$true)][int]$MaxMins
    )

    begin { 
        "THE START" 
        $StartTime = Get-Date
        $StopTime = (get-date).AddMinutes($MaxMins)
        "Stop time is: $StopTime"

        # Embedded cleanup function.
        function clean-up {
          "THE END"
        }

    } 

    process 
    {  
        $currTime = Get-Date
        if( $currTime -lt $StopTime ){
            "Processing $Foo"            
        }
        else {
            # Call the cleanup function just before stopping the pipeline.
            clean-up
            continue;
        }
    }

    end { 
      # Normal termination: call the cleanup function.
      clean-up
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A new block has been added in PowerShell 7.3, `Clean`, that executes at the end regardless of whether or not the pipeline was completed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.3