# PowerShell: Dispose objects when pipeline stopped

Tags: powershell, pipeline, dispose, powershell-cmdlet

I was wondering how to properly dispose objects in scripted cmdlets when the pipeline was stopped.

Usually I would initialize the disposable object in the `begin` block, work with it in the `process` block, and finally dispose it in the `end` block:

```
function Example {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [byte]$Value
    )
    begin {
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
    }
    process {
        $stream.WriteByte($value)
    }
    end {
        $stream.Dispose()
    }
}
```

But the `end` block is not executed when the pipeline is stopped (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for example). And I cannot dispose the object in the `process` block because I need it for the next step in the pipeline.

I posted one possible approach as an answer. But is there any more robust solution?

*(Note: This is about scripted cmdlets only, not compiled.)*

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28522507/4137916).

Answer (score 2):

This is one workaround I came up with:

(Tested in Powershell v5)

```
function Example {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [byte]$Value
    )
    begin {
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
    }
    process {
        try {
            $dispose = $true
            $stream.WriteByte($value)
            # indicate that the process block finished normally
            $dispose = $false
        }
        finally {
            # detect stopped pipeline
            if ($dispose) {
                if ($stream) {
                    $stream.Dispose()
                    $stream = $null
                }
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        # regular dispose
        if ($stream) {
            $stream.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently there is a request on [Github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6673) to introduce a new `Dispose` block or similar, which would be a great and much needed improvement IMHO.

Comment: This doesn't actually work -- Ctrl-C will interrupt all processing, including the `finally` block. You can verify this is the case by putting a `sleep` in the `process` and then something that should do something (like `del canaryfile`) in the `finally` -- it won't run if you interrupt it. This is quite unlike how things work in regular .NET languages. You don't notice in this case because `MemoryStream.Dispose` is essentially a no-op (and I wouldn't worry about calling it in PowerShell at all). For other classes (like `StreamWriter`) it's more of an issue.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is **not** correct. I just verified it again, using your example even. The finally block was run even after I pressed CTRL+C and the file was deleted as expected. Have you tested this recently? I am using PS v5 btw.

Comment: @JeroenMostert And yes, I do know disposing is not much of an issue with MemoryStream. I am actually more concerned about file and db streams. I just wanted something simple and non-critical for example purposes.

Comment: Yes, I have tested this very code, with PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10. Neither a `del` nor a deliberate syntax error do anything in the `finally` when I press Ctrl-C. So it's quite weird that we're getting different results! Are you interrupting it from the PowerShell prompt or the ISE (or some custom pipeline runner maybe)? Whether I invoke it standalone or with input and output in a pipeline makes no difference either.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, I tried both ISE and regular PowerShell prompt. Same behavior. I put the code I used for testing in my answer. Run it and press ctrl+c right after "begin" is printed: You should see "finally" printed after that anyways.

Comment: Another  test code (one line)`function Example {process {write-host "sleeping now!"; try {sleep 10 ; "Everything is fine!"} finally { write-host "It's Finally!" }} end {write-host "It's the End!"}}` You will see that finally is used when you press ctrl +c but the endblock is NOT! But that is exactly what try-catch-finally is build for.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. If you put the `Sleep` inside the `try` block of the `process`, then yes -- the `finally` runs if the `try` is actually entered. If you put it anywhere else (I put it right after the initialization in the `begin`), the `end` block still never gets hit. So if your `begin` is "really fast", and you make sure to put the `process` in a try-finally, and the interrupt doesn't hit between elements... it's something.

Comment: The only significant problem is the last one: try piping the output of `function Slow-Producer { $i = 0; while ($true) { Write-Output $i; $i++; Sleep 5 } }` to this cmdlet. That's contrived, of course, but real life pipelines that stall or slowly produce elements aren't unusual. This is not useless, but be aware of its limitations.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, your last example, is the real problem. That's exactly why this is just an insufficient workaround.